# iframe defined as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My iframe should close on red button clicked and should sometimes change its src but chrome thinks my iframe is null. here's my website: https://broenot.netlify.com/articles/20-11-18
Here's my code from banners.js:

```
var bannerid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var bannerclosed = localStorage.getItem("bannerclosed");
  if (bannerclosed == "yes"){
    document.getElementById("ibanner").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  if (bannerid == 1){
    document.getElementById("ibanner").src = "/banners/banner2.html";
  }
  $('#banner').load(function(){
    var iframe = $('#ibanner').contents();
    iframe.find("#close").click(function(){
      $("#ibanner" ).animate({opacity: 0}, 500)
      setTimeout(bannerclose, 500); 
    });
  });
  function bannerclose(){
    document.getElementById("ibanner").style.visibility = "hidden";
    localStorage.setItem("bannerclosed", "yes");
  }
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="/banners/banner1.html" frameborder="0" style="width: 40%; height: 150px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; border-radius: 15px;" id="ibanner"></iframe>
```

Get other things on the website using F12 if you need.

Comment: What is your error, what line trigger the error?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar iframe url isn’t changing and if you visited the page “close” button doesn’t work

Comment: sorry I visited your page but that's not clear. I don't see any close button on your page. It would be better if you could create a jsfiddle that reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok It's because I was using Firefox. In Chrome I see the close btn

Comment: did you mean to use `#ibanner` as the selector instead of `#banner` ??

Answer (score 0):

The url wont change if you just set a localStorage item. First, you have to add an event listener on the [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) event:

**Edit**: Use `.ready()` instead of `.load()` for disambiguity

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event){
    if (event.storageArea === localStorage) {
        var bannerclosed = localStorage.getItem("bannerclosed");
        if (bannerclosed == "yes"){
            document.getElementById("ibanner").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        if (bannerid == 1){
            document.getElementById("ibanner").src = "/banners/banner2.html";
        }
    }
}, false);

$('#ibanner').ready(function(){
  var $iframe = $('#ibanner');
  $iframe.find("#close").click(function(){
    $iframe.animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
    setTimeout(bannerclose, 500); 
  });
});

function bannerclose(){
    document.getElementById("ibanner").style.visibility = "hidden";
    localStorage.setItem("bannerclosed", "yes");
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ jQuery likes to "overload" many of the methods. you can use .load to wait for the load event.

Comment: @rlemon ok so the problem is that code to change the url is not called after the close button was clicked

Comment: My current guess is there is a typo in the selector (which you've corrected in your version)

Comment: yes and the url wont change if there is no event listener for the localStorage

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Window still not closes or changes url

Comment: @Jake is `$('#ibanner').load()` function is called? Then is the `$iframe.find("#close").click()` function is called when you click on the button?

Comment: Do a simple `console.log("ibanner ready)` inside `$('#ibanner').ready()` and a `console.log("on close btn clicked")` inside `$iframe.find("#close").click()` to verify if they are both called